# Bad Interpreter: No such file or directory - Mac/Django/Terminal

Tags: django, macos, terminal, pip, easy-install

If I try to run anything using `pip` in Terminal on Mac I get the following error:

```
(oby)$ pip freeze
-bash: /Users/s4l1818/Desktop/oby/bin/pip: /Users/s4l1818/Desktop/test/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

However, if I go into the bin directory of my Django project, pip and easy_install are both installed.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Have you created virtualenv with sudo?

Comment: @moonstruck I was looking back at history, and I ran this command: `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev` which deactivates the active virtualenv. Is there a way to re-activate a virtualenv?

Comment: To reactivate go to created environment directory. `source bin/activate`  To deactivate just `deactivate`